# Can I use embedded Javascript in a ghost blog entry?

Tags: javascript, ghost-blog

I am using the [Ghost Blogging Software](http://ghost.org) and tumbled over [Tangle](http://worrydream.com/Tangle/) these days. So it would be great to be able to use that in some of my Blog posts.

I have included the Tangle-files in my theme and load them in `default.hbs`. However, I cannot find a way to embed some javascript (to be executed, but not displayed) in the markdown document. I would like to write the javascript in the markdown document too as I do not want to add js-Files to my theme each time I write a blog post with *reactive content*.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems there is. You should be able to include the JavaScript you want to run by just placing it inside of `<script>` tags like they talk about on [this post](https://ghost.org/forum/using-ghost/16677-embedding-javascript-widgets/)

Edit: To further explain, a markdown file is just different syntax for creating html tags, but you can use regular html and script tags inside them. To get an script to run per the above link, you should only need to include whatever js you want to run inside of the script tags. This example should work inside of a markdown post file to replicate the Tangle example on the doc page

```
When you eat <span data-var="cookies" class="TKAdjustableNumber"> cookies</span>,
you consume <span data-var="calories"> calories</span>.

<script>
var tangle = new Tangle(document, {
    initialize: function () { this.cookies = 3; },
    update:     function () { this.calories = this.cookies * 50; }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, I found that before. Unfortunately it is kind of impractical (and otherwise ugly) to add some js-files to my theme each time I want to post some _reactive content_. I will update the question to make that clear.

Comment: You don't have to add js files to your theme. You've already stated you added the Tangle files to your default.hbs, which is all you need. In your markdown file now all you have to do is write `<script> callSomeFunctionFromTangle(); </script>`

Comment: Alright, after fixing some dumb mistakes including 2 typos the script gets embedded - but not executed unfortunately: http://christianpfanner.at/tangle/ Any ideas why?

Comment: Seems to be an issue with Tangle. It can't call addEvent as it's undefined on your span element TKAdjustableNumber (that's the error in the console anyway).

Comment: Guess I have to look into how Ghost loads its components a little closer. The initial question however, is definitely answered.